# CSS - width and maximised windows

Tags: css

I have a bit of CSS which displays data in 4, 2 or 1 column as the window
width diminishes.
The relevant bit of code is...

```
@media screen and (max-width:1900px) {
            .col {
 width: 25%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width:1010px) {
                .col {
     width: 50%;
  }
}   
    @media screen and (max-width:540px) {
                .col {
     width: 95%;
  }
}
```

It works absolutely perfectly except for one thing - if you maximise the 
browser window, the data changes to a single column!

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with maximizing browser window but I guess that you have at least fullhd screen which is 1920+px. None of your rules get catched and default is 100% width.

I would say that make default value as 25% of width

```
.col {
  width: 25%;
}
```

or change first rule into something like below.

```
@media screen and (min-width:1011px) {
  .col {
    width: 25%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set width's for different types per max-width. Try to use min-width for all width's over 1010px.

```
@media screen and (min-width:1011px) {
            .col {
 width: 25%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width:1010px) {
                .col {
     width: 50%;
  }
}   
    @media screen and (max-width:540px) {
                .col {
     width: 95%;
  }
}
```